# jQuery: Checking for disabled attribute and adding/removing it?

Tags: jquery, forms, serialization, attributes

I select all input elements of a form like this:

```
var fields = $( form + " :input" ).not( "button" );
```

How do I check if any of these inputs has the `disabled` attribute set and remove it when present?

Also, I need to add it after is has been removed (and serialize the fields in between), is there an elegant way for this? Something like `toggle` but for attributes?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQuery 1.6 or above, the suggested method is to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

`fields.prop("disabled", false);`

If you need to have logic around each one, you could do something to the extent of

```
var fields = $( form + " :input" ).not( "button" );
fields.each(function(index, element) {
    var isDisabled = $(element).is(':disabled');
    if (isDisabled) {
        $(element).prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        // Handle input is not disabled
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBntG/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `disabled` selector

```
$('input:disabled').attr('disabled', '');
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/)

http://jsfiddle.net/JngR9/

Answer (score 1):

use [:disabled Selector](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/)`
try this

```
$('input:disabled').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

To Remove

```
$('input:disabled').removeProp('disabled');
```

or

```
$('input:disabled').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

To Add

```
$('input:disabled').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```